# how to show in listview??(using okhttp library)

Tags: java, android, json, listview, okhttp

```
                @Override
                public void onResponse(final Response response) throws IOException {//okhttp onresponse method
                try {


                String json = response.body().string();//get data from cinemalytics
                Log.v(TAG, json);//
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    mCurrentmovie = getDATA(json);

   //mCurrentmovie is an object of Currentmovie getter and setter class.


                       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            String T = mCurrentmovie.getTitle();
                            tv.setText(T);


  //successfully show in single textview but can't in listview


                        }
                    });


                } else {

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }


        }
    });
```

//return json object

```
      private Currentmovie getDATA(String json) throws JSONException {

    JSONArray values = new JSONArray(json);
    // JSONArray values = object.getJSONArray("0");


    // JSONObject ob = object.getJSONObject("0");
    JSONObject obj = values.getJSONObject(0);
    String Title = obj.getString("Title");
    String imgg = obj.getString("PosterPath");
    Currentmovie c = new Currentmovie();

    c.setImageView(imgg);

    Log.e(TAG, Title);

    c.setTitle(Title);

    return c;


}
```

//i want this data in listview image also included in data.please tell step by step
   //json data from cinemalytics

```
        [

{
    "Id": "7582268f",
    "ImdbId": "tt0979913",
    "OriginalTitle": "Life Mein Kabhie Kabhiee",
    "Title": "Life Mein Kabhie Kabhiee",
    "Description": "",
    "TrailerLink": "",
    "TrailerEmbedCode": "",
    "Country": "IN",
    "Region": "BOLLYWOOD",
    "Genre": "",
    "RatingCount": 1,
    "Rating": 2.0,
    "CensorRating": "",
    "ReleaseDate": "1/1/1900",
    "Runtime": 0,
    "Budget": 0,
    "Revenue": 0,
    "PosterPath": "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/cinemalytics/movie/70C66638BF359AEA9E9FEE83AE46D18C.jpg"
}
```

]

//movieAdapter class
//shows error in getSystemService,rest of all code is ok....

```
     package com.example.maau.movieinfo;

                        import android.content.Context;
                         import android.view.LayoutInflater;
                            import android.view.View;
                         import android.view.ViewGroup;
                       import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
                          import android.widget.ImageView;
                         import android.widget.TextView;

                          import java.util.List;


                       public class MovieAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


                         private List<Currentmovie> movieData;
                        private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

                      public MovieAdapter(List<Currentmovie> movieData)
                      {
            this.movieData = movieData;
inflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);                           
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return movieData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return movieData.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }


        public static class ViewHolder{
            public TextView movieTitle;
            public ImageView movieImage;

        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {


            View vi = convertView;
            ViewHolder holder;

            if(convertView==null){
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.movieTitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv);
            //    holder.movieImage=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);

                vi.setTag( holder );
            }
            else
                holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();



            holder.movieTitle.setText(movieData.get(position).getTitle());


            return vi;
        }
    }
```

Comment: please anyone tell asap.its urgent for me.(@problem is able to show in textview but can't show data in listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**After getting response follow below code,**

First create below 2 elements at top out side of all methods.

```
    List<CurrentMovie> moviesList = new ArrayList<>();
    MovieAdapter mAdapter;

 // Now on response change code as below
   
   if (response.isSuccessful()) {

        manageJson(json);
    }



public void manageJson(String result)
{
   try
   {
        movieList = new ArrayList<>();
       JsonArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

       for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
       {
             JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJsonObject(i);
      
             String Title = obj.getString("Title");
             String imgg = obj.getString("PosterPath");
              Currentmovie c = new Currentmovie();

              c.setImageView(imgg);
              c.setTitle(Title);

              movieList.add(c);                 
       }

       mAdapter = new MovieAdapter(YourActivityName.this, movieList);
       listViewObject.setAdapter(mAdapter);
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
       System.out.println("Error in Result as " + e.toString());
   }
}
```

**Now Take one Adapter to set Data in ListView**

```
public class MovieAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private final Context context;
    private List<CurrentMovie> movieData;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

    public MovieAdapter(Context context, List<CurrentMovie> movieData)
     {
         this.context = context;
         this.movieData = movieData;
         inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     } 

     @Override
     public int getCount() {
         return movieData.size();
     }

     @Override
     public Object getItem(int position) {
         return movieData.get(position);
     }
  
     @Override
     public long getItemId(int position) {
         return position;
     }
      
   
     public static class ViewHolder{              
         public TextView movieTitle;
         public ImageView movieImage;
  
     }
  
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
     {
          
         View vi = convertView;
         ViewHolder holder;
          
         if(convertView==null){
             vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabitem, null);

             holder = new ViewHolder();
             holder.movieTitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.title);
             holder.movieImage=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
              
             vi.setTag( holder );
         }
         else 
             holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
          
        

              holder.movieTitle.setText(movieData.get(position).getTitle());
             
              
         return vi;
     }
 }
```

Comment: yes,it resolved. if i m correct then tabitem is the name of layout file where i am going to put a title textview...

Comment: Yes it is your layout file for listview, as how you want to show your list view, so add imageview and title there ....For more details check list_row.xml file in http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

Comment: vicky all things are going in right way..but it showing a blank layout where it should show listitem...i can't understand why??

Comment: i have created two xml:-- row.xml(contain title) to show the type of listview and movie.xml for containing listview...

Comment: give me following details

Name of your activity in which you are working,

Name of xml file which you have set as content view on above activity

and elements list of xml file which you have taken in xml file

Comment: name of my xml and activity are movie.java and movie.xml(listview) and just for learning purpose firstly i want to get only title from cinemalytics json link...in listview and row.xml for textview of listview....

Comment: and i didn't create any item.xml file in resource because i want to get data from cinemalytics json formatted https link...so is it needed??

Comment: can you please point out your changes or give me the location where i did mistake...

Comment: Check below points:
You were setting adapter from the method which was executing from another thread, so there this will not work you need to pass application context at that time in adapter.
You are setting names and ids which are keyword, so you should not do this anytime, like for ListView you have set id as ListView, both type and id same so don’t do this.
above 2nd point applicable for variables also, as you have taken one variable with name Title, then don’t take same in same class file keep name safe so you can get better output.

That’s it.

Comment: you can upvote and accept answer if it is working for you

Comment: now it's working....thanx a lot...please if ques. is suitable,upvote my ques. it would help me...