# ListView with image and text from JSON using ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, json

I know to get the `ListItem` from:

```
string[] = {"data1","data","data3"};
```

But how do I get it from a JSON response? I moved my data to:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>
```

My code is below, I have to use JSON instead of getting a `String[]` because my JSON response contains an id, a title and an image link.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] titles,header;
    ListView list1;
    int[] img;
    String[] title;
    int[] img = {R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img3};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);


        title ={"data1","data2","data3"}

        myAdapter adapter = new myAdapter(getApplicationContext(), titles, img);


        list1.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    class myAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        Context context;
        int[] imgs;
        String[] titles;


        private ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<>();
        private ArrayList<Integer> mImage = new ArrayList<>();
        private TreeSet<Integer> sectionHeader = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        myAdapter(Context context, String[] titles, int imgs[]) {
            super(context, R.layout.list_item, R.id.text, titles);
            this.context = context;
            this.imgs = imgs;
            this.titles = titles;
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }


        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            int rowType = getItemViewType(position);

            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

                        holder.myImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);

                        holder.myText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.texttitle);


                        Picasso.with(context)
                                .load(imgs[position])
                                .fit()
                                .into(holder.myImage);

                        holder.myText.setText(titles[position]);
                        convertView.setTag(holder.myImage);



            return convertView;
        }

        public class ViewHolder {
            public TextView myText;
            public ImageView myImage;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Please provide your json response.

Comment: @Drv the json response like[ { "id":"1","data":"data1"},{"id":"2","data":"data2"}]

Comment: while using simple adapter it shows like can't resolve the bitmap

Comment: Please post your complete code if possible.

Comment: check my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37905218/how-to-show-in-listviewusing-okhttp-library/37942092#37942092

Comment: @Lavanya page is not found

Comment: @RathigaJesika Check this "https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLsoBxH455yoZZeeza9TiG8I9dGP0zz5o9&v=0Lr37suTPpg" out there in description you will get link to code. It is available with source code too. You need to create new Adapter Class extending ArrayAdapter http://www.wingnity.com/blog/android-json-parsing-and-image-loading-tutorial/.

Comment: @Lavanya please make this comment as answer... bcz its working perfectly. i used glide instead of AsyncTask to load image.

Comment: I have created answer as per your request. Please comment if you face any problem while implementation.

Answer (score 0):

First change your above code by below so that you can see the list of image and string properly:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView list1;
String[] title = {"data1", "data2", "data3"};
;
int[] img = {R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);


    myAdapter adapter = new myAdapter(getApplicationContext(), title, img);


    list1.setAdapter(adapter);

  }
}

class myAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
Context context;
int[] imgs;
String[] titles;


private ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Integer> mImage = new ArrayList<>();
private TreeSet<Integer> sectionHeader = new TreeSet<Integer>();
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

myAdapter(Context context, String[] titles, int imgs[]) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item, R.id.text, titles);
    this.context = context;
    this.imgs = imgs;
    this.titles = titles;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    int rowType = getItemViewType(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        holder.myImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);

        holder.myText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.texttitle);

        holder.myImage.setImageResource(imgs[position]);


   //            Picasso.with(context)
   //                    .load(imgs[position])
   //                    .fit()
   //                    .into(holder.myImage);

        holder.myText.setText(titles[position]);
        convertView.setTag(holder.myImage);


    }
    return convertView;

}

  public class ViewHolder {
    public TextView myText;
    public ImageView myImage;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Rathiga Jesika Please learn everything first and then try to call data from server and then try to convert json and load it in app.

Comment: I used Picasso lib function. bcz it helps to load more image.