# android ListActivity how to populate data with Json Volley Library

Tags: android, android-volley

android ListActivity  how to make Custom Adapter getter setter using ,call json Volley library populate data ListActivity ? could not populate data with Json how to implement  ,Please Help me 
my code

**ItemFragment Class**

```
public class ItemFragment extends ListActivity {
RequestParse requestParse;
MySharedPreferences prefs;
String UsrId;
Context context;
ArrayList<BizForumArticleInfo> list = new ArrayList<>();
private List<BizForumArticleInfo> CountryCodeNumber = new ArrayList<>();

MobileArrayAdapter adapter;
LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view_android_example);
    requestParse = new RequestParse();
    prefs = MySharedPreferences.getInstance(this, SESSION);
    UsrId = prefs.getString("UsrID", "");
    context = getApplicationContext();
    setListAdapter(new MobileArrayAdapter(this,0, list));

    getJson(60);
}

public void getJson(final int limit){
    requestParse.postJson(ConfigApi.postArticleBiz(), new RequestParse.VolleyCallBackPost() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String result) {
            list = parseResponse(result);

        }
        @Override
        public void onRequestError(String errorMessage) {
        }
        @Override
        public Map OnParam(Map<String, String> params) {
            params.put("sessionid", UsrId);
            params.put("offset", "0");
            params.put("limit", String.valueOf(limit));
            params.put("viewtype", "all");
            params.put("access_token","e3774d357aa7d4bd14e9763b5459ee9cf7ebe36161c142551836ee510d98814a:b349b76b334a94b2");
            return params;
        }
    });
}
public static ArrayList<BizForumArticleInfo> parseResponse(String response) {
    ArrayList<BizForumArticleInfo> bizList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray(DATA);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            BizForumArticleInfo ls = new BizForumArticleInfo();
            JSONObject item = data.getJSONObject(i);
            String ArticleTitle = item.getString("ArticleTitle");
            String Article = item.getString("Article");
            M.i("===================",ArticleTitle);//working
            ls.setArticleTitle(ArticleTitle);
            ls.setArticleArticle(Article);
            bizList.add(ls);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bizList;
}
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, selectedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("selectedValue", selectedValue);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();


    //startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class));

}
}
```

**Adapter Class**

```
public class MobileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BizForumArticleInfo> {
private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<BizForumArticleInfo> lPerson;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public MobileArrayAdapter (Activity activity, int textViewResourceId,ArrayList<BizForumArticleInfo> _lPerson) {
    super(activity, textViewResourceId, _lPerson);
    try {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.lPerson = _lPerson;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

public int getCount() {
    return lPerson.size();
}

public BizForumArticleInfo getItem(BizForumArticleInfo position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView display_name;
    public TextView display_number;

}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;
    try {
        if (convertView == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_mobile, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.display_name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.label);
            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }



        holder.display_name.setText(lPerson.get(position).getArticleTitle());


    } catch (Exception e) {


    }
    return vi;
}
}
```

Comment: after parsing the result (json) you need to notify adapter that the data has changed, so after list = parseResponse line you need adapter.notifydatasetchanged method.

Comment: check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37905218/how-to-show-in-listviewusing-okhttp-library/37942092?noredirect=1#comment63421922_37942092

Comment: remove this `setListAdapter(new MobileArrayAdapter(this,0, list));` from `onCreate` write it inside `OnSuccess()` after this line `list = parseResponse(result);`